# (the) university of

Tags: articles, definite-article

Is the article 'the' used to universities which do not have the word 'university' in their title?

We can say, for instance:

- The University of Toronto
- The University of Helsinki

Yet, should we say or not:

- The Harvard
- The Sciences Po
- The Oxford

How should we refer these universities, if we mean their name (title)?
Should we use the article 'the' or not?

Comment: I'm not a native therefore my opinion can't be reliable but I didn't come across 'The Harvard' or 'The Sciences Po' with articles

Comment: It's similar to the fact that you can say "the Republic of Ireland" but not *"the Ireland".

Comment: @rjpond – Thus, we have to omit 'the' here, don't we?

Comment: @LoveLanguagesAndPeople Correct, we wouldn't refer to "the Oxford", "the Harvard" or "the Sciences Po". We do refer to "the Sorbonne", though.

Comment: 'The University of Oxford' _is_ it's official name, but informally people say 'Oxford University' or just 'Oxford' (if the context makes it plain that the university and not the city is being referred to).

Comment: Same as "The artist formerly known as Prince" -- but we don't (didn't) say "The Prince". At least, not in the context of "Prince Nelson".

Comment: Related? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139866/xyz-university-vs-the-university-of-xyz

Comment: As one can see from [the page about its seal](https://brand.jhu.edu/academic-seal/), even though my alma mater itself uses the name *Johns Hopkins University* in many contexts, its official  name—the one found on the seal—is ***The** Johns Hopkins University*.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is whether the official title is The University of X not just whether its title contains the word university. For instance there are two universities in the English city of Bath: The University of Bath and Bath Spa University. For the first you would use The but not for the second. This is not an isolated example there are others like De Montfort University, Anglia Ruskin University which would not take the article. For ones whose title does not include university it is true that we do not usually add the article. It is hard to give a rule which would cover names in other languages. For instance I would say ETH Zürich without an article but in German I imagine it might be different. Your example of Sciences Po is interesting as its full name does have an article in French even though it is commonly known by the abbreviated form.

Comment: But if you abbreviated "University of Bath" to "Bath University" or to "Bath", there would be no article. So it's not simply a question of what the official name is, but also whether you are using the "U of X" form (which takes an article) or the "X University" form (which doesn't take an article - though I think someone found an exception in the US).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say "The Harvard".

The official title of many universities is in one of two forms: "The University of York"  (a British institution) or "York University" (a Canadian one).  The article is part of the full name only in the first case.

In either case we may sometimes shorten the name of the University. "I studied Maths at York".  When we do this, it doesn't matter if we mean "York University" or "The University of York".  If we shorten the name, you don't use an article.

So you'd say "I studied at Harvard" or "... at Science Po", or "... at Oxford".

And remember that although "The University of Oxford" is the most famous, there are several other universities and colleges in Oxford.