# Is there a guide for using the article "the" or not when referring to a university name?

Tags: articles, definite-article, nouns

Consider this pair of sentences

> This book is an outgrowth of our involvement in teaching … at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology.

> This book is an outgrowth of our involvement in teaching … at Massachusetts Institute of Technology.

The second version seems incorrect because of missing the article "the".

Consider another pair of sentences

> This book is an outgrowth of our involvement in teaching … at the MIT.

> This book is an outgrowth of our involvement in teaching … at MIT.

In this case the version with "the" seems incorrect.

Is there a guide for using the article "the" or not when referring to a university name?

The sentences are adapted from http://athenasc.com/probpreface.html

Comment: @JavaLatte Thank you. In your link, the actual name of the building is "La Scala" and there is no need to use an article. In my OP, the actual name is "Massachusetts Institute of Technology" and does need an article. How does your link relate to my OP?

Comment: How about [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/276788/the-university-of)?

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I guess your link is close to my OP though, they're different. Consider this pair of sentences, "This book is an outgrowth of our involvement in teaching … at **the** Bath Spa University" and "This book is an outgrowth of our involvement in teaching … at Bath Spa University," I guess the version without "the" is grammatically correct, but why is the version with "the" in the first pair in my OP grammatical?

Comment: Not being American, I don't know how MIT is commonly referred to. By analogy with Bath Spa University, the version without _the_ would seem correct - but I can also see a case for using _the_ in the same way that we say **the Greater London Council**.